# VB.Net format array date

Tags: arrays, vb.net

When writing the array to excel range date is in an incorrect format

Have tried many ways to format the value if it's a date value but unable to get it working correctly.

```
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim items As Object() = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray
    For j = 0 To items.Length - 1
 my2DArray(i, j) = items(j)     

IF IsDate (items(j)) Then
my2DArray(i, j) = Format(items(j), "{dd/MM/yyyy}")
End if

    Next
Next
```

When adding to the array I need to check if the value is a date.

If the value is a date I need to format the date to `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to do either of those things. If you haven't tried then it's too soon to be posting a question here. If you have tried then show us your best attempt. For all you know, there's just one tiny error that we can correct. It is NEVER for us to just write code for you. It is always for us to help you fix the issues with your code. If you don't show us what you have done then there's no issues for us to fix.

Comment: To check it it's a date, use [DateTime.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Once parsed, call `.ToString()` against the date and pass in your [Custom Date Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Code has been updated with what i tried but cant get to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim items As Object() = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray
    For j = 0 To items.Length - 1
        If IsDate (items(j)) Then
            my2DArray(i, j) =CDate(items(j)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        Else
            my2DArray(i, j) = items(j)
        End if
    Next
Next
```